# get followers twitter like using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

hello lets say i have an example

my follow table

```
A B
1 2 // same so its friend
2 1 // same so its a friend
1 3 // user 1 is following 3
1 4 // user 1 is following 4
```

etc

lets say we are the user 1 how can we list our friends ?
i have something in my head like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM social WHERE ((A = B) = (B = A)) as friends
// so it will be something like count friends where ( 1 = 2 ) = ( 1 = 2) if you get my logic
```

or can we do that somehow ?

if it work it will count as 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT COUNT(me.A) FROM social AS me 
   INNER JOIN social AS you ON me.B = you.A 
WHERE me.A = you.B AND me.A = 1
```

Remove the `COUNT` if you want a list of friends.

**EDIT**

As requested, an explanation.

You're `JOIN`ing a table to itself because you're interested in the relationships between rows.

I decided to alias the tables as `me` and `you` to make the relationship clear. What that is saying is that column `A` can refer to me as the *follower* or you as the follower. Column `B` refers to the *followee*

If you were to rename the columns, the query would read more clearly

if `A` -> `follower` and `B` -> `followee`, we'd have:

```
SELECT COUNT(me.follower) FROM social AS me 
   INNER JOIN social AS you ON me.followee = you.follower
WHERE me.follower = you.followee AND me.follower = 1
```

So it's saying, take two copies of this table and `JOIN` the rows where the followee in  `me` is the follower in `you`. Then, filter and show only the rows where the follower in `me` is the followee in `you`... there by capturing your desire to have `(A == B) && (B == A)`

Perhaps the table aliases aren't that great, but I hope that clarifies a little.

**SECOND EDIT**
Per comments below, a clearer form may be:

```
SELECT COUNT(me.A) FROM social AS me 
   INNER JOIN social AS you ON me.A = you.B AND me.B = you.A
WHERE me.A = 1
```

Comment: if you have time can you describe it splits i still cant get the logic. btw thanks dancrub it works perfectly

Comment: Logically the join condition is `me.B = you.A AND me.A = you.B`, and the filter condition is only `me.A = 1`. So maybe, just maybe, your solution would be slightly clearer without any explanation if you arranged them accordingly. Still it's correct either way, of course.

Comment: @Andriy M: After some thought, I think you're right. I'm always wary of putting WHERE conditions into JOIN ON conditions (and vice versa) as I've seen (and committed) some major sins in this area. However, I think you're definitely right with regards to clarity and most probably right with regards to appropriateness.

Comment: Ooh, that nasty `AND` after `WHERE`! Why couldn't it just vanish? It's my fault, I shouldn't have started this and you wouldn't have left it there mistakenly.

Comment: @Andriy M: I don't know *what* you're talking about ;o)