# twitter-style follower/following/friend sql query

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a twitter type of following system. I'm joining two tables, users and followers to get the first and lastname of users who are in the followers table. Then I'm running an inner join on the followers table to capture follower and friend relationships. I'm displaying the results as followers (who follows you), following (who you follow), and friends (mutual following).

With the query below, I'm only able to show the name of the user who wants to see their friends. I'd like to show the FRIENDS of the user, not the user's own name, but can't figure out how to get the users table to do double duty--that is, show me the name of the user and the name of their friend, or just the friend's name.

Thanks.

```
SELECT users.id, users.firstname, users.lastname, followers.follower_user_id, followers.followee_user_id
            FROM users
            JOIN followers ON followers.follower_user_id = users.id
            INNER JOIN followers ff ON followers.followee_user_id = ff.follower_user_id AND followers.follower_user_id = ff.followee_user_id
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that your schema requires a union table to assemble the information you need; and it may be more efficient to do this in multiple tables. To maintain a separate table of followers with (possible) duplicate information from users may also be undesireable. A more efficient schema would be:

```
mysql> select * from users;
+-----+------------+---------+
| uid | fname      | lname   |
+-----+------------+---------+
|   1 | Phillip    | Jackson |
|   2 | Another    | Name    |
|   3 | Some Crazy | User    |
|   4 | Nameless   | Person  |
+-----+------------+---------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select * from follows;
+---------+-----------+
| user_id | follow_id |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 |         4 |
|       2 |         3 |
|       3 |         2 |
|       4 |         2 |
+---------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And then your query would look like:

```
select users.uid,
users.fname,
users.lname,
u.uid,
u.fname,
u.lname from users
inner join follows f on (f.user_id=users.uid)
inner join users u on (u.uid=f.follow_id)
```

Which returns:

```
mysql> select users.uid,
    -> users.fname,
    -> users.lname,
    -> u.uid,
    -> u.fname,
    -> u.lname from users
    -> inner join follows f on (f.user_id=users.uid)
    -> inner join users u on (u.uid=f.follow_id);
+-----+------------+---------+-----+------------+--------+
| uid | fname      | lname   | uid | fname      | lname  |
+-----+------------+---------+-----+------------+--------+
|   1 | Phillip    | Jackson |   4 | Nameless   | Person |
|   4 | Nameless   | Person  |   2 | Another    | Name   |
|   2 | Another    | Name    |   3 | Some Crazy | User   |
|   3 | Some Crazy | User    |   2 | Another    | Name   |
+-----+------------+---------+-----+------------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Using this method it's easy to get both information about a user who follows you, but derive whether they follow you back or not. Very efficient and done in one query; just requires a rearchitecture.

Comment: If you want a quickstart - here's the schema in a pastie: http://pastebin.com/4UPwAYPX

Comment: Thank you for this. The table setup you suggested is what my current setup is like. I'm going to try this new query and will be back shortly with a response.

Comment: Works beautifully. I have accepted an upvoted your answer. Quick question about the friend query: I can see how to derive info on who you follow and who follows you--but how do you get information on the mutual relationship?

Comment: You can do this with application logic, but if you require to get it from a db query you can use the following SO article to help you understand how it works. This could be added as a column on your select with a subquery. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113195/get-followers-twitter-like-using-mysql

Comment: Thanks. I used that initial question as a model for the query in my question. I'd rather use application logic. Right now, I can pull the follower_user_id information for a user id, or the followee_user_id information for a user id. But I can't figure out how to get the data where the follower and followee are each following each other. I'll keep trying. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name, uf.id, uf.first_name, uf.last_name
FROM    users u
JOIN    followers f
ON      f.follower_user_id = u.id
JOIN    followers ff
ON      (ff.followee_user_id, ff.follower_user_id) = (f.follower_user_id, f.followee_user_id)
JOIN    users uf
ON      uf.id = f.followee_user_id
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Am going to try it out now.

Comment: I upvoted your answer; this query worked well to identify friends friends. I selected the other answer only because it allows me to identify followers and friends from one query.

Comment: I mean it worked well to identify friends, not friends of friends.