# php logic for follower/followee

Tags: php, codeigniter

**Update: I figured it out. See my answer below.**

I'm trying to write some logic at the application level to identify the friends (mutual followers)in the table below. My query has returned the data in a format similar to the table below (borrowed from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113195/get-followers-twitter-like-using-mysql) question, but I don't need a query, that part's done):

```
A B
1 2 // mutual followers, so "friends"
2 1 // mutual followers, so "friends"
1 3 // user 1 is following 3
1 4 // user 1 is following 4
```

So how can I write some logic which shows the users where A = B and B = A, but in different rows? Using PHP/codeigniter.

In response to a request, here's the SQL tables and query:

```
Users table - uid, fname, lname
Followers table - user_id, follow_id

Select users.uid, users.fname, users.lname, u.uid, u.fname, u.lname
FROM users
INNER JOIN follows f on (f.user_id=users.uid)
INNER JOIN users u on (u.uid=f.follow_id)
```

Comment: Are you asking how to run the SQL query provided in the example you linked to?

Comment: No. I've got the query working and it produces the results below. (It's a different query). Just trying to create the logic.

Comment: What do you mean in different rows? What's the expected output?

Comment: This is the friendship list of user #1 right?

Comment: @tpaksu: This is a list of all the follower relationships. You see user 1 is following user 2, user 2 is following user 1, and user 1 is also following user 3 and user 4. User 1 and 2 are following each other so they are "friends". I am trying to pull user 1 and 2 only.

Comment: Ok, but there's a current user right? And you are filtering it by the relations that user #1 has?

Comment: @Claudiu - The expected output would be 1 and 2. I am trying to get only the users that are following each other.

Comment: @tpaksu - Yes, there is a current user (user 1) and I'm filtering the data by the user 1's relationships.

Comment: I would do this through your SQL rather than your PHP for both performance issues and purely because I believe the logic belongs there. Can we see some table structures?

Comment: @Lock I added the SQL query above.

Comment: @Lock and added the tables also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. I needed a second INNER JOIN for the followers table. I added the code below to my SQL query, and it worked.

```
INNER JOIN followers f2 ON u.id = f2.user_id AND users.id = f2.follow_id
```

Comment: Glad to see this in action. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for your help earlier--wouldn't have been able to get it going otherwise. After I used your fix, then I tried the application logic and just couldn't get it to work. Someone suggested doing it in mySQL (which I didn't want to do), but I tinkered with it for a couple of hours and finally got it to go.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
$results = array(array(1,2),array(2,1),array(1,3),array(1,4));
$mutual_users = array_filter($results,function($elem)use($results){
    if(in_array(array_reverse($elem),$results)){
        return true;
    }
});
print_r($mutual_users);
```